# How to find $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n}})$?

Tags: limits

I am trying to solve this : $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n}})$ but I always end up with $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$ which is undefined

I tried for eg $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n}}) (\frac {\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n}})$$
which resulted in:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {n^2(\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-(\frac 1n)^\frac12)}{n^2}$$

but I cannot seem to find any other solutions

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done indeed

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {n^2(\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-(\frac 1n)^\frac12)}{n^2}= \frac {(\sqrt{1+0}-(0)^\frac12)}{1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Why not just that way?
$$\frac {n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n}} = \frac{n}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}1$$

Comment: I thought the fraction n/n would be undefined. So when it crosses out, I don't need to worry about that?

Comment: @LaurenSin : No need to worry about that. It is definitely equal to $1$. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the numerator and the denominator by $n^2$, then it won't be undeterminated anymore.